# Nested for loop duplicates results

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to copy data across multiple sheets into one sheet. The problem I have is that it duplicates the result of one sheet that fits the IF-statement 5 times (as I have 5 sheets). How would this be solved in VBA?

```
Dim Current As Worksheet
Dim j As Integer
Dim Target As Worksheet

Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CopyToThis")

j = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
    For Each Current In Worksheets
        For Each c In Current.Range("I:I")
            If c > 0 Then
                MsgBox (Current.Name)
               Current.Rows(c.Row).Columns("A:F").Copy Target.Rows(j) 'Copy only columns A to F
               j = j + 1
            End If
        Next c
    
    Next
```

Comment: Well you'll need to introduce some sort of check of what is already there.

Comment: Like, if already checked the worksheet then skip or something? But I don't understand why it's going through the worksheets that many times already..

Comment: Your code goes through each sheet once, and but then loops through a million cells in each, which is probably unnecessary.

Comment: Guess I could change that, but then it's still strange it loops over every sheet more than once..

Comment: Your code as posted doesn't do that, so there must be other code.